# How to use Lead() and Lag() to get the first non null value

Tags: sql, sql-server, window-functions

I have the following query

```
SELECT tb2.event_id, 
       tb2.MENU_HINT, 
       tb2.EVENT_NAME, 
       tb2.Expr1003, 
       tb2.CountWinnerNotPrice55to89Runners0to1 AS columnCount, 
       tb2.SumWinnerNotPrice55to89Runners0to1 AS columSum, 
       lead(tb2.SumWinnerNotPrice55to89Runners0to1,1)  OVER(   order by tb2.expr1003) as lead1
FROM [dbo].[tblData2] tb2
WHERE tb2.Expr1003 = '01/01/2018 ';
```

and returns this table:

```
╔═══════════╦══════════════════════════╦═════════════════╦════════════╦═════════════╦══════════╦═══════╗
║ event_id  ║ MENU_HINT                ║ EVENT_NAME      ║ Expr1003   ║ columnCount ║ columSum ║ lead1 ║
╠═══════════╬══════════════════════════╬═════════════════╬════════════╬═════════════╬══════════╬═══════╣
║ 138466815 ║ AUS / Long (AUS) 1st Jan ║ R4 1400m Hcap   ║ 01/01/2018 ║ 1           ║ 85.00    ║ NULL  ║
╠═══════════╬══════════════════════════╬═════════════════╬════════════╬═════════════╬══════════╬═══════╣
║ 138466809 ║ AUS / Long (AUS) 1st Jan ║ R1 1400m Mdn    ║ 01/01/2018 ║ 0           ║ NULL     ║ NULL  ║
╠═══════════╬══════════════════════════╬═════════════════╬════════════╬═════════════╬══════════╬═══════╣
║ 138466868 ║ AUS / MBdg (AUS) 1st Jan ║ R7 1206m Hcap   ║ 01/01/2018 ║ 0           ║ NULL     ║ NULL  ║
╠═══════════╬══════════════════════════╬═════════════════╬════════════╬═════════════╬══════════╬═══════╣
║ 138466189 ║ AUS / Inve (AUS) 1st Jan ║ R7 1400m Hcap   ║ 01/01/2018 ║ 0           ║ NULL     ║ NULL  ║
╠═══════════╬══════════════════════════╬═════════════════╬════════════╬═════════════╬══════════╬═══════╣
║ 138466864 ║ AUS / MBdg (AUS) 1st Jan ║ R5 1406m Hcap   ║ 01/01/2018 ║ 0           ║ NULL     ║ NULL  ║
╠═══════════╬══════════════════════════╬═════════════════╬════════════╬═════════════╬══════════╬═══════╣
║ 138386493 ║ AUS / Rand (AUS) 1st Jan ║ R2 1600m Hcap   ║ 01/01/2018 ║ 0           ║ NULL     ║ NULL  ║
╠═══════════╬══════════════════════════╬═════════════════╬════════════╬═════════════╬══════════╬═══════╣
║ 138466862 ║ AUS / MBdg (AUS) 1st Jan ║ R4 904m Hcap    ║ 01/01/2018 ║ 0           ║ NULL     ║ 82.53 ║
╠═══════════╬══════════════════════════╬═════════════════╬════════════╬═════════════╬══════════╬═══════╣
║ 138386464 ║ AUS / Flem (AUS) 1st Jan ║ R5 1700m Hcap   ║ 01/01/2018 ║ 1           ║ 82.53    ║ NULL  ║
╠═══════════╬══════════════════════════╬═════════════════╬════════════╬═════════════╬══════════╬═══════╣
║ 138466813 ║ AUS / Long (AUS) 1st Jan ║ R3 1400m Hcap   ║ 01/01/2018 ║ 0           ║ NULL     ║ NULL  ║
╠═══════════╬══════════════════════════╬═════════════════╬════════════╬═════════════╬══════════╬═══════╣
║ 138386488 ║ AUS / Asct (AUS) 1st Jan ║ R9 1200m Hcap   ║ 01/01/2018 ║ 0           ║ NULL     ║ 57.45 ║
╠═══════════╬══════════════════════════╬═════════════════╬════════════╬═════════════╬══════════╬═══════╣
║ 138466522 ║ AUS / Morn (AUS) 1st Jan ║ R4 1200m Hcap   ║ 01/01/2018 ║ 1           ║ 57.45    ║ 65.00 ║
╠═══════════╬══════════════════════════╬═════════════════╬════════════╬═════════════╬══════════╬═══════╣
║ 138386468 ║ AUS / Flem (AUS) 1st Jan ║ R7 2800m Listed ║ 01/01/2018 ║ 1           ║ 65.00    ║ NULL  ║
╠═══════════╬══════════════════════════╬═════════════════╬════════════╬═════════════╬══════════╬═══════╣
║ 138466181 ║ AUS / Inve (AUS) 1st Jan ║ R3 1010m Hcap   ║ 01/01/2018 ║ 0           ║ NULL     ║ NULL  ║
╠═══════════╬══════════════════════════╬═════════════════╬════════════╬═════════════╬══════════╬═══════╣
║ 138466187 ║ AUS / Inve (AUS) 1st Jan ║ R6 1600m Hcap   ║ 01/01/2018 ║ 0           ║ NULL     ║ NULL  ║
╠═══════════╬══════════════════════════╬═════════════════╬════════════╬═════════════╬══════════╬═══════╣
║ 138386486 ║ AUS / Asct (AUS) 1st Jan ║ R8 2400m Grp2   ║ 01/01/2018 ║ 0           ║ NULL     ║ NULL  ║
╠═══════════╬══════════════════════════╬═════════════════╬════════════╬═════════════╬══════════╬═══════╣
║ 138386480 ║ AUS / Asct (AUS) 1st Jan ║ R5 1600m Hcap   ║ 01/01/2018 ║ 0           ║ NULL     ║ 65.00 ║
╠═══════════╬══════════════════════════╬═════════════════╬════════════╬═════════════╬══════════╬═══════╣
║ 138386478 ║ AUS / Asct (AUS) 1st Jan ║ R4 1800m Grp3   ║ 01/01/2018 ║ 1           ║ 65.00    ║ NULL  ║
╠═══════════╬══════════════════════════╬═════════════════╬════════════╬═════════════╬══════════╬═══════╣
║ 138386497 ║ AUS / Rand (AUS) 1st Jan ║ R4 1200m Hcap   ║ 01/01/2018 ║ 0           ║ NULL     ║ NULL  ║
╠═══════════╬══════════════════════════╬═════════════════╬════════════╬═════════════╬══════════╬═══════╣
║ 138386476 ║ AUS / Asct (AUS) 1st Jan ║ R3 2200m Hcap   ║ 01/01/2018 ║ 0           ║ NULL     ║ NULL  ║
╠═══════════╬══════════════════════════╬═════════════════╬════════════╬═════════════╬══════════╬═══════╣
║ 138466177 ║ AUS / Inve (AUS) 1st Jan ║ R1 1010m Mdn    ║ 01/01/2018 ║ 0           ║ NULL     ║ NULL  ║
╠═══════════╬══════════════════════════╬═════════════════╬════════════╬═════════════╬══════════╬═══════╣
║ 138466856 ║ AUS / MBdg (AUS) 1st Jan ║ R1 904m Mdn     ║ 01/01/2018 ║ 0           ║ NULL     ║ NULL  ║
╠═══════════╬══════════════════════════╬═════════════════╬════════════╬═════════════╬══════════╬═══════╣
║ 138466518 ║ AUS / Morn (AUS) 1st Jan ║ R2 1200m 3yo    ║ 01/01/2018 ║ 0           ║ NULL     ║ NULL  ║
╠═══════════╬══════════════════════════╬═════════════════╬════════════╬═════════════╬══════════╬═══════╣
║ 138386470 ║ AUS / Flem (AUS) 1st Jan ║ R8 1400m Hcap   ║ 01/01/2018 ║ 0           ║ NULL     ║ NULL  ║
╠═══════════╬══════════════════════════╬═════════════════╬════════════╬═════════════╬══════════╬═══════╣
║ 138386466 ║ AUS / Flem (AUS) 1st Jan ║ R6 1200m Grp3   ║ 01/01/2018 ║ 0           ║ NULL     ║ 66.51 ║
╠═══════════╬══════════════════════════╬═════════════════╬════════════╬═════════════╬══════════╬═══════╣
║ 138466191 ║ AUS / Inve (AUS) 1st Jan ║ R8 1400m Cup    ║ 01/01/2018 ║ 1           ║ 66.51    ║ NULL  ║
╠═══════════╬══════════════════════════╬═════════════════╬════════════╬═════════════╬══════════╬═══════╣
║ 138466798 ║ AUS / Tera (AUS) 1st Jan ║ R5 1125m Hcap   ║ 01/01/2018 ║ 0           ║ NULL     ║ 70.00 ║
╠═══════════╬══════════════════════════╬═════════════════╬════════════╬═════════════╬══════════╬═══════╣
║ 138466821 ║ AUS / Long (AUS) 1st Jan ║ R7 1800m Hcap   ║ 01/01/2018 ║ 1           ║ 70.00    ║ 72.44 ║
╠═══════════╬══════════════════════════╬═════════════════╬════════════╬═════════════╬══════════╬═══════╣
║ 138386462 ║ AUS / Flem (AUS) 1st Jan ║ R4 2000m Hcap   ║ 01/01/2018 ║ 1           ║ 72.44    ║ 72.42 ║
╚═══════════╩══════════════════════════╩═════════════════╩════════════╩═════════════╩══════════╩═══════╝
```

now, what I'm trying to do is to calculate the lead of the first non null value on the field. for example, for event_id = 138466815 the **columnCount**  is 85. 
I want the "lead1" field to show  82.53, which is the next non null value below. and that then later, for event_id = **138386464 **  "lead 1 to show 57.45 (the next not null value below).

I'm not sure if I should pass a parameter to the offset parameter of the lead function, but I don't know which one should be, maybe something with Coalesce? I wasn't able to do it.

just to put it a bit more clear, this is what I expect the lead1 column to show:

```
╔═══════════╦══════════════════════════╦═════════════════╦════════════╦═════════════╦══════════╦═══════════════╗
║ event_id  ║ MENU_HINT                ║ EVENT_NAME      ║ Expr1003   ║ columnCount ║ columSum ║ lead1         ║
╠═══════════╬══════════════════════════╬═════════════════╬════════════╬═════════════╬══════════╬═══════════════╣
║ 138466815 ║ AUS / Long (AUS) 1st Jan ║ R4 1400m Hcap   ║ 01/01/2018 ║ 1           ║ 85.00    ║ 82.53         ║
╠═══════════╬══════════════════════════╬═════════════════╬════════════╬═════════════╬══════════╬═══════════════╣
║ 138466809 ║ AUS / Long (AUS) 1st Jan ║ R1 1400m Mdn    ║ 01/01/2018 ║ 0           ║ NULL     ║ NULL          ║
╠═══════════╬══════════════════════════╬═════════════════╬════════════╬═════════════╬══════════╬═══════════════╣
║ 138466868 ║ AUS / MBdg (AUS) 1st Jan ║ R7 1206m Hcap   ║ 01/01/2018 ║ 0           ║ NULL     ║ NULL          ║
╠═══════════╬══════════════════════════╬═════════════════╬════════════╬═════════════╬══════════╬═══════════════╣
║ 138466189 ║ AUS / Inve (AUS) 1st Jan ║ R7 1400m Hcap   ║ 01/01/2018 ║ 0           ║ NULL     ║ NULL          ║
╠═══════════╬══════════════════════════╬═════════════════╬════════════╬═════════════╬══════════╬═══════════════╣
║ 138466864 ║ AUS / MBdg (AUS) 1st Jan ║ R5 1406m Hcap   ║ 01/01/2018 ║ 0           ║ NULL     ║ NULL          ║
╠═══════════╬══════════════════════════╬═════════════════╬════════════╬═════════════╬══════════╬═══════════════╣
║ 138386493 ║ AUS / Rand (AUS) 1st Jan ║ R2 1600m Hcap   ║ 01/01/2018 ║ 0           ║ NULL     ║ NULL          ║
╠═══════════╬══════════════════════════╬═════════════════╬════════════╬═════════════╬══════════╬═══════════════╣
║ 138466862 ║ AUS / MBdg (AUS) 1st Jan ║ R4 904m Hcap    ║ 01/01/2018 ║ 0           ║ NULL     ║ NULL          ║
╠═══════════╬══════════════════════════╬═════════════════╬════════════╬═════════════╬══════════╬═══════════════╣
║ 138386464 ║ AUS / Flem (AUS) 1st Jan ║ R5 1700m Hcap   ║ 01/01/2018 ║ 1           ║ 82.53    ║ 57.45         ║
╠═══════════╬══════════════════════════╬═════════════════╬════════════╬═════════════╬══════════╬═══════════════╣
║ 138466813 ║ AUS / Long (AUS) 1st Jan ║ R3 1400m Hcap   ║ 01/01/2018 ║ 0           ║ NULL     ║ NULL          ║
╠═══════════╬══════════════════════════╬═════════════════╬════════════╬═════════════╬══════════╬═══════════════╣
║ 138386488 ║ AUS / Asct (AUS) 1st Jan ║ R9 1200m Hcap   ║ 01/01/2018 ║ 0           ║ NULL     ║ NULL          ║
╠═══════════╬══════════════════════════╬═════════════════╬════════════╬═════════════╬══════════╬═══════════════╣
║ 138466522 ║ AUS / Morn (AUS) 1st Jan ║ R4 1200m Hcap   ║ 01/01/2018 ║ 1           ║ 57.45    ║ 65.00         ║
╠═══════════╬══════════════════════════╬═════════════════╬════════════╬═════════════╬══════════╬═══════════════╣
║ 138386468 ║ AUS / Flem (AUS) 1st Jan ║ R7 2800m Listed ║ 01/01/2018 ║ 1           ║ 65.00    ║ NULL          ║
╠═══════════╬══════════════════════════╬═════════════════╬════════════╬═════════════╬══════════╬═══════════════╣
║ 138466181 ║ AUS / Inve (AUS) 1st Jan ║ R3 1010m Hcap   ║ 01/01/2018 ║ 0           ║ NULL     ║ NULL          ║
╠═══════════╬══════════════════════════╬═════════════════╬════════════╬═════════════╬══════════╬═══════════════╣
║ 138466187 ║ AUS / Inve (AUS) 1st Jan ║ R6 1600m Hcap   ║ 01/01/2018 ║ 0           ║ NULL     ║ NULL          ║
╠═══════════╬══════════════════════════╬═════════════════╬════════════╬═════════════╬══════════╬═══════════════╣
║ 138386486 ║ AUS / Asct (AUS) 1st Jan ║ R8 2400m Grp2   ║ 01/01/2018 ║ 0           ║ NULL     ║ NULL          ║
╠═══════════╬══════════════════════════╬═════════════════╬════════════╬═════════════╬══════════╬═══════════════╣
║ 138386480 ║ AUS / Asct (AUS) 1st Jan ║ R5 1600m Hcap   ║ 01/01/2018 ║ 0           ║ NULL     ║ NULL          ║
╠═══════════╬══════════════════════════╬═════════════════╬════════════╬═════════════╬══════════╬═══════════════╣
║ 138386478 ║ AUS / Asct (AUS) 1st Jan ║ R4 1800m Grp3   ║ 01/01/2018 ║ 1           ║ 65.00    ║ 66.51         ║
╠═══════════╬══════════════════════════╬═════════════════╬════════════╬═════════════╬══════════╬═══════════════╣
║ 138386497 ║ AUS / Rand (AUS) 1st Jan ║ R4 1200m Hcap   ║ 01/01/2018 ║ 0           ║ NULL     ║ NULL          ║
╠═══════════╬══════════════════════════╬═════════════════╬════════════╬═════════════╬══════════╬═══════════════╣
║ 138386476 ║ AUS / Asct (AUS) 1st Jan ║ R3 2200m Hcap   ║ 01/01/2018 ║ 0           ║ NULL     ║ NULL          ║
╠═══════════╬══════════════════════════╬═════════════════╬════════════╬═════════════╬══════════╬═══════════════╣
║ 138466177 ║ AUS / Inve (AUS) 1st Jan ║ R1 1010m Mdn    ║ 01/01/2018 ║ 0           ║ NULL     ║ NULL          ║
╠═══════════╬══════════════════════════╬═════════════════╬════════════╬═════════════╬══════════╬═══════════════╣
║ 138466856 ║ AUS / MBdg (AUS) 1st Jan ║ R1 904m Mdn     ║ 01/01/2018 ║ 0           ║ NULL     ║ NULL          ║
╠═══════════╬══════════════════════════╬═════════════════╬════════════╬═════════════╬══════════╬═══════════════╣
║ 138466518 ║ AUS / Morn (AUS) 1st Jan ║ R2 1200m 3yo    ║ 01/01/2018 ║ 0           ║ NULL     ║ NULL          ║
╠═══════════╬══════════════════════════╬═════════════════╬════════════╬═════════════╬══════════╬═══════════════╣
║ 138386470 ║ AUS / Flem (AUS) 1st Jan ║ R8 1400m Hcap   ║ 01/01/2018 ║ 0           ║ NULL     ║ NULL          ║
╠═══════════╬══════════════════════════╬═════════════════╬════════════╬═════════════╬══════════╬═══════════════╣
║ 138386466 ║ AUS / Flem (AUS) 1st Jan ║ R6 1200m Grp3   ║ 01/01/2018 ║ 0           ║ NULL     ║ NULL          ║
╠═══════════╬══════════════════════════╬═════════════════╬════════════╬═════════════╬══════════╬═══════════════╣
║ 138466191 ║ AUS / Inve (AUS) 1st Jan ║ R8 1400m Cup    ║ 01/01/2018 ║ 1           ║ 66.51    ║ 70.00         ║
╠═══════════╬══════════════════════════╬═════════════════╬════════════╬═════════════╬══════════╬═══════════════╣
║ 138466798 ║ AUS / Tera (AUS) 1st Jan ║ R5 1125m Hcap   ║ 01/01/2018 ║ 0           ║ NULL     ║ NULL          ║
╠═══════════╬══════════════════════════╬═════════════════╬════════════╬═════════════╬══════════╬═══════════════╣
║ 138466821 ║ AUS / Long (AUS) 1st Jan ║ R7 1800m Hcap   ║ 01/01/2018 ║ 1           ║ 70.00    ║ 72.44         ║
╠═══════════╬══════════════════════════╬═════════════════╬════════════╬═════════════╬══════════╬═══════════════╣
║ 138386462 ║ AUS / Flem (AUS) 1st Jan ║ R4 2000m Hcap   ║ 01/01/2018 ║ 1           ║ 72.44    ║ next not null ║
╚═══════════╩══════════════════════════╩═════════════════╩════════════╩═════════════╩══════════╩═══════════════╝
```

Also, I'm not sure if there is a way to count the amount of rows between the first not null value in "columnCount" and the second not null value.  for example to have 7 as the first count, 3 as the second and 1 as the third.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to want the next value where `columnCount = 1`, so partition by that column:

```
   lead(tb2.SumWinnerNotPrice55to89Runners0to1, 1) over
       (partition by columnCount
        order by tb2.expr1003
       ) as lead1
```

Comment: This kinda solves it, but is there a way to do it and maintain the order? this method does group it in the proper way, but messes up the order, I need to have it as I have it now, the original table is sorted by Expr1003 desc, raceno desc.  I have added this to the lead() but it doesn't seem to work

Comment: @Baldie47 . . . Tables are not ordered.  If you want the result in a particular order, then you need to add an `order by` clause to your query; in your case, `order by exp_1003, raceno desc`.

Comment: this ended up working well, I was missing to order by one third field (event_id) as the exp_1003 and raceno combination wasn't unique, so it was mixing result order